# Duplicate relationships on multiple nodes using merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a project where a user creates an event and then he can invite his friends to that event. I'm trying to find a query to create an `:INVITED` relationship between the event and the users invited.

I'm using the following query to achieve that which works just fine.

```
MATCH (e:Event {event_id: '592c815a98048121c400299b'})
MATCH (u:User) 
WHERE u.username IN ["one", "two", "three"] 
MERGE (e)-[:INVITED {invited_by: "692c812a98048121c4004ac3"}]->(u)
return u;
```

The problem is that if I run the same query twice, all the relationships are created again and then I have duplicate results.

Using `MERGE` in my query should prevent it from creating the same relationship again. Any idea what might wrong?

PS I've also tried with `CREATE UNIQUE` still the same results

Comment: Does your `invited_by` property is everytime the same ?

Comment: Yes it's the same

Comment: What version are you using ? It's look like a bug ...

Comment: I'm using 3.2.0

Comment: Can you test on a 3.2.1 ? It's working on my laptop ... (first excuse of a dev. :))

Comment: I tested here in Neo4j 3.2.0 and it worked fine...